# why is snprintf changing the second string?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

I am trying to concatenate two strings using snprintf and it works for very small strings, eg. 1 or 2 characters, any more and this kind of thing happens. The last character of the first string is repeated

```
int main()
{
    char str1[] = "foo", str2[] = "bar", str3[]= "";

    printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2);

    snprintf(str3, strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1, "%s %s", str1, str2);

    printf("%s", str3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo bar
foo oo
```

Comment: `str3` is not big enough to hold both `str1` and `str2`.

Comment: Change `str3[] = ""` to `*str3 = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1)`.

Comment: And don't forget to `free(str3)` when you're done using it...

Comment: If you ever have *any* snprintf call where the second argument isn't directly related to the allocation of the first argument, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Don't be confused by your results.  The fact you even get `foo oo` in the second `printf()` statement is an artifact of undefined behavior.  Only one byte of space is _owned_ by the variable `str3`.  It just so happened that additional bytes that were not yet _owned_ by any other entity were available to accept some input.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem with C. Just because it works doesn't mean it actually works :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `str3` is not big enough to hold both `str1` and `str2`.

Since you initialize `str3` with `""` the size of `str3` will be set to `1`.

Here the correct way:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // snprintf
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc, free
#include <string.h> // strlen

int main() {
    char str1[] = "foo";
    char str2[] = "bar";
    // We need to dynamically allocate the third buffer
    // since its size is not determined at compile time.
    // The size we need is the length of str1, str2, + 1 for a space
    // and + 1 for the NUL terminator.
    size_t str3_size = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 2;

    char *str3 = malloc(str3_size);

    // NULL = out of memory
    if (!str3) {
        printf("oops!"); return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    snprintf(str3, str3_size, "%s %s", str1, str2);

    printf("%s", str3);

    // Don't forget to free malloc'd memory!
    free(str3);
}
```

If you are using a C99 compiler you can drop the malloc entirely and allocate the third buffer on the stack like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // snprintf
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // strlen

int main() {
    char str1[] = "foo";
    char str2[] = "bar";
    // The size we need is the length of str1, str2, + 1 for a space
    // and + 1 for the NUL terminator.
    size_t str3_size = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 2;

    char str3[str3_size];

    snprintf(str3, str3_size, "%s %s", str1, str2);

    printf("%s", str3);
}
```

*But be careful though, allocating dynamic sized memory on the stack can be dangerous!*

There is also a function `asprintf` (GNU extension) which automatically calculates the right size. Here the same example with it:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // asprintf
#include <stdlib.h> // free

int main() {
    char str1[] = "foo";
    char str2[] = "bar";
    char *str3 = NULL;

    asprintf(&str3, "%s %s\n", str1, str2);
    // str3 now contains a pointer to the allocated memory :)

    // NULL = out of memory
    if (!str3) {
        printf("oops!"); return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("%s", str3);

    // Don't forget to free malloc'd memory!
    free(str3);
}
```

Comment: Maybe mention `strcat` too?

Comment: please be aware that `asprintf()` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Could you not also simply use `char str3[str3_size]` as the third buffer?

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes but this is a C99 feature.

Comment: @d3l best to mention that feature also, just in case.

Comment: Why is this good answer receiving downvotes? And no comment for the reason.